# Polling with session idle timeout

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, single-sign-on

I am using Single Sign on for all the applications in Tomcat. My requirement here is, I have to poll status of transaction which should be fetched from back end. But it should not affect the idle timeout of the session also.

Could anybody suggest if something could be done?

Thanx

Comment: Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you can use filter to check when last time session is used by requests other than your pooling and invalidate session manually

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

@Slf4j
@Component
@Order(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class SessionTimeoutExcludeUrlsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  private final static String INCLUDED_LAST_ACCESS_TIME = "includedLastAccessTime";

  private final Set<String> sessionTimeoutExcludeUrls;

  public SessionTimeoutExcludeUrlsFilter(@Value("${http.session.timeout.exclude-urls}") Set<String> sessionTimeoutExcludeUrls) {
    this.sessionTimeoutExcludeUrls = sessionTimeoutExcludeUrls;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse,
      FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = httpRequest.getSession();
    if (!sessionTimeoutExcludeUrls.contains(httpRequest.getRequestURI())) {
      session.setAttribute(INCLUDED_LAST_ACCESS_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    if (session.getAttribute(INCLUDED_LAST_ACCESS_TIME) != null) {
      long includedLastAccessTime = (Long) session.getAttribute(INCLUDED_LAST_ACCESS_TIME);
      if (System.currentTimeMillis() - includedLastAccessTime > session.getMaxInactiveInterval() * 1000L) {
        session.invalidate();
        log.info("Invalidating session {} by inactive timeout", session.getId());
      }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(httpRequest, httpResponse);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a standard way to do this. If not, you could write a filter.

In the filter, ignore requests that do not count (e.g. your polling request).

For other requests, check the last request time (which you should have saved in the session). If a long-enough time has elapsed end the session. Otherwise, save the new time.

Clearly, you'll have to see what overhead this adds, but -- with a few tweaks -- it should work.

Answer (score -2):

Simple way to do is to create a Servlet something called PulseServlet and call it from Javascript or JQuery AJAX code in regular intervals of time to get the status. But, this affects the Session timeout on the server. Without affecting Session Timeout you can't do this. But, if you really want Session timeout not to be affected you need to reset the session timeout programatically.

Comment: Could you please explain more reset session timeout programatically?

Comment: When you say back-end, are you trying to get the status from same web application or it doesn't matter if you are referring to database?

Comment: The simple way to do it but it doesn't do it?

Comment: It's does. What's the problem with my solution?