# Session with Idle Timeout - but how to define non-keeping-alive actions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-state

Is it possible to configure an ASP.NET (MVC) web application to have a session timeout (idle timeout) that is not affected by certain web requests (for example, some AJAX requests)?

I know that the following is possible:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="5"/></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

This way, the session will expire upon 5 minutes of inactivity (that is, not making any web requests).

Also, there is an attribute that allows you to enable / disable the session for a particular controller:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehaviour.Disabled)] 
public class MyController : Controller   
{ 
}
```

Though, I am interested in defining an action whose call does not participate in any way to the timeout of the session, but, nonetheless, can access session variables.

That is, I would like to define an action that, if called, **does not keep the session alive**, does not *slide* the session interval, but it can read session variables.

Is this possible? I believe not, but anyway :)

Perhaps a clearer rephrasing:

**Can I define a web action that can access session variables, but does not keep the session alive, does not increase its lifetime?**

Some links:

- [Session Expiration](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_Expiration)
- [SessionState Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.sessionstateattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Related post:
[Polling with session idle timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900972/polling-with-session-idle-timeout)